# Django form.save(commit=False) with request.session

Tags: django-forms, django-views, django-sessions

I am trying to understand form.save(commit=False) with session in django. From the docs

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

it is mentioned that when you use form.save(commit=False) it returns you the object but is not saved to the database yet (which is good for me). So, i store the object in session and then when i later retrieve it, i am not able to retrieve the same object.

I get a DoesNotExist Error which is true, since it is not stored in the database i guess.

Is there a way i can store the object in session and later retrieve to update the form. 
Or could anyone point in the right direction if i am going wrong.

My view is as follows.

```
def create(request):
   if request.POST:
      form = EventForm(request.POST)
      form .save()
      del request.session['event_id']
      return HttpResponseRedirect('/Event')
   else:
      event_session = request.session.get('event_id')
      if event_session is not None:
         event_instance = EiEvent.objects.get(eventID = event_session)
         edit_form = EiEventForm(instance = event_instance)
      else:
         form = EventForm()
         a = form.save(commit=False)
         request.session['event_id'] = a
   args = {}
   args.update(csrf(request))
   args['form'] = form
   return render_to_response('event.html', args)
```